# google maps listener only working once, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map on my page that alternates with an image using jQuery.
My google map listener looks for mouseover and mouseout events and stops the alternation with the image, this works, however only works once, and the listener seems to be removed, so I can 'pause' the map to view it by moving my mouse over, and resume the 'alternation' with mousing off of the map, however when I want to pause the animation to view the map again it will not pause. I can't seem to reactive the listener.

my jQuery

```
    function switchBox() {
    $('#imagebox7img').toggle('slow', 'linear');
    $('#map-canvas').toggle('slow', 'linear');
}

$('#imagebox7img').hide();

var interval = setInterval(switchBox, 5000);
```

Google maps code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);


google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'mouseover', function() {
mouseoverInterval(map);
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'mouseout', function() {
mouseoutInterval(map);
});


    function mouseoverInterval(map) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        }

    function mouseoutInterval(map) {
        setInterval(switchBox, 5000);
        }

 }
```

Comment: Are the listeners in pageinit?

Comment: I have only used $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: Try in pageinit if that works.

Comment: map doesn't load if I use $(document).on("pageinit",function(){

Comment: You have to set `interval = setInterval(switchBox, 5000);` in `mouseoutInterval()` function. Additionally, I'd use `addListener()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in method:

```
function mouseoutInterval(map) {
    setInterval(switchBox, 5000);
}
```

which set interval back but variable handler `interval`  is not set again. It should be changed to

```
function mouseoutInterval(map) {
    interval = setInterval(switchBox, 5000);
}
```

Additionally, I'd use `addListener()`.